# Huawei HMS Maps Android Codelab not working

Tags: android, dictionary, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I am trying to use the Huawei Maps Kit for the new devices that don't include Google Play Services. Codelab demo is located at:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSMapKit/index.html#7

I haven't changed any single line of code of the demo and the app has automacally downloaded Huawei Mobile Services version 3.0.3.300.

However, the map still does not appear.

Did you face the same problem?

I am getting this logs:

`01-26 14:24:34.265 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo W/DynamicModule: Failed to load remote module.`

```
01-26 14:24:34.256 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo D/HmsMapKit_MapView_183: onStart
01-26 14:24:34.257 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_48: Making Createor dynamically
01-26 14:24:34.257 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/DynamicModule: Local module huawei_module_maps:0
01-26 14:24:34.257 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/DynamicModule: Remote module huawei_module_maps:-100
01-26 14:24:34.259 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo W/DynamicModule: Failed to load remote module.
    com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: f*i*e* *o*l*a* *o*u*e
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getRemoteContext(MapCreator.java:97)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getRemoteMapContext(MapCreator.java:85)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getCreator(MapCreator.java:50)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView$MapViewDeferredLifecycleHelper.createDelegate(MapView.java:241)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onStart(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView.onStart(MapView.java:184)
        at com.wz.android.mapdemo.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1245)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6330)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6376)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6381)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1543)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
01-26 14:24:34.259 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo E/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_99: getRemoteContext: DynamicModule load failedcom.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: failed to load Module
01-26 14:24:34.261 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_53: getRemoteMapContext failed
01-26 14:24:34.263 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo D/HmsMapKit_MapView_166: onResume
01-26 14:24:34.263 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_48: Making Createor dynamically
01-26 14:24:34.263 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/DynamicModule: Local module huawei_module_maps:0
01-26 14:24:34.264 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/DynamicModule: Remote module huawei_module_maps:-100
01-26 14:24:34.265 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo W/DynamicModule: Failed to load remote module.
    com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: f*i*e* *o*l*a* *o*u*e
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getRemoteContext(MapCreator.java:97)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getRemoteMapContext(MapCreator.java:85)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.internal.MapCreator.getCreator(MapCreator.java:50)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView$MapViewDeferredLifecycleHelper.createDelegate(MapView.java:241)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onResume(Unknown Source)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView.onResume(MapView.java:167)
        at com.wz.android.mapdemo.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1268)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1543)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
01-26 14:24:34.265 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo E/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_99: getRemoteContext: DynamicModule load failedcom.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: failed to load Module
01-26 14:24:34.267 19265-19265/com.wz.android.mapdemo I/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_53: getRemoteMapContext failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javier,   I have just checked information in Huawei Developer web site https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-map-v4-abouttheservice. There is "Restrictions" section 3.1  and it is stated there that only for Huawei devices.

Comment: My fault, Push Kit can be used in any device but Maps Kit only in Huawei devices. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sample project for HMS Map from Codelab and it works fine for all devices ( with GMS and without GMS).
 Did you modify anything in the sample code ( gradle.build, json files etc.) or just downloaded the sample code and build it to run?
I mean that probably you followed the procedure in Codelab and used sample project as a reference and updated some files based on the instruction?

Please provide more information

Comment: I have just downloaded the project and compiled it. I have not changed any file. The app has automacally downloaded Huawei Mobile Services version 3.0.3.300.

Still not working :S

Comment: In which country are you testing it? I am in Spain. Does it have anything to do with it ?

Comment: Hello Javier!  the latest HMS version is 4.0.0.334 not 3.0.3.300.  Could you try to update the HMS version? You can use Huawei AppGallery for that.

Comment: I am in Finland.   But what kind of device are you using : "the new devices that don't include Google Play Services" ? Is it Huawei device ?

Comment: I have installed manually Huawei Services 4.0.0.334 and still not working. It is not a Huawei Device, but AFAIK it is only required to install these Huawei Services in order to test in other devices or in an emulator.

Comment: Javier,   I have just checked information in Huawei Developer web site https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-map-v4-abouttheservice. There is "Restrictions" section 3.1  and it is stated there that only for Huawei devices.

Comment: What version of the Map Kit are you using

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Phone→Setting→Apps→search: Huawei Services Framework, uninstall it*
2. Phone→Setting→Apps→search: Huawei Mobile Service, uninstall it*
3. Phone→AppGallery→search: Huawei Mobile Service, install it

*If it is not possible to uninstall the services then try to deactivate them and uninstall their updates if you are prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, HUAWEI Map Kit can only run and be used on Huawei phones. We are focusing on the decoupling now so that more capabilities can run on non-Huawei phones. For HMS Core capabilities that can run on non-Huawei phones, please refer to [EMUI Version-Dependent Features](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/emui-version-dependent-0000001050042515). If **Not supported** is displayed in the **Required Android Version (Non-Huawei Phones)** column, the corresponding capability can only run on Huawei phones; if specific Android versions are displayed in this column, the corresponding capability can run on non-Huawei phones running such versions of Android systems.

Comment: Good day! The note says "Android 7.0 does not support apps that have a platform signature.". What do you guys mean by that? Thanks

Comment: hi@Bitwise DEVS, The link above is a previous document, and I have updated the latest document in my answer, you can refer that. The latest document does not contain "Android 7.0 does not support apps that have a platform signature." restriction now.

Comment: Great, thank you. Does this mean that we can now test HMS Map Kit in non Huawei device as well?

Comment: Also I cannot see the Map Kit in the table from the given link

Comment: Does this mean that we can now test HMS Map Kit in non Huawei device as well?--sure,pls kindly refer to [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-brief-introduction-0000001061991343#section1261123620147).It's the latest document for the map kit

Comment: Many thanks, lastly can we run it on emulator since it is never mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Of course you can. And you can also use [huawei cloud debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-adjust) to test it.

Comment: That's great! Thank you

Comment: You‘re welcome.Should you need help with anything else, please feel free to reach out back to us.

Comment: Yes we do have problem with HMS Core, please refer to this question thank you https://stackoverflow.com/q/69004914/12204620

Answer (score 0):

To download the demo, you need to create a project on AGC, add your own sha256, and download the JSON file to your app-level directory. The map can be properly displayed.