# HMS Core APK to install and run on x86

Tags: android, android-emulator, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

We do not have Huawei device yet so we want to use emulator for the mean time, the problem is HMS Core can only be installed on ARM while emulator usually run on x86 which is 10x faster. Even there is an ARM image available on AVD we can't rely on that since it is very slow as it trying to emulate the ARM CPU & GPU to the point where you can't really use it for the development at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. Currently, Huawei HMS Core apk does not support the x86 CPU architecture. Even if the x86 is supported, installing the HMS Core apk on the existing simulator may not be effective because most of HMS Core kits depend on the EMUI version and the background running of the HMS Core apk.

If Huawei devices are not available, you may use the [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-adjust/?ha_source=hms1) service provided by [Huawei Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/?ha_source=hms1) to run your applications on the ARM environment. For details, kindly check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/cloud-debugging-0000001051084360).

Comment: Cloud Debugging is really great, nice move! However some device like Mate 30 seems not working very well as it hangs after unlocking the screen while Mate 30 Pro seems having difficulty with Location Kit. So far P40 and P40 Pro works fine.

Comment: hi@Bitwise DEVS, Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue? 
If there is a screenshot, it would be better. we can try to fix why the Mate 30 Pro does not work properly.

Comment: You may post it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and tag with [huawei-mobile-services] then we can trace this issue.